# LoadRunner Scheduler - can I pause VUSERS?

Tags: loadrunner

My LoadRunner scenario uses 100 VUSERS, running for 3 days, and I have to pause the scenario during maintenance window time (01:00 - 02:00).
Since I'm short of VUSERS (my license is for 100 VUSERS), I cannot stop them at 01:00 and restart them at 02:00, since it means I'm using 200 VUSERS.

Is there a method to hold/freeze/pause the test, and continue it later on?

Previously I used the following:
1. Start 100 VUSERS.
2. Run until 01:00
3. Stop VUSERS.
4. Start 100 VUSERS
5. Run until 01:00
6. ...
As I said, in this method I'm exceeding my VUSERS pool.
Any ideas?

Thanks, Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of the iteration programmatically check the system clock and if you are within your iteration window of touching 1:00am then fall into sleep command for the appropriate number of milliseconds until 2:00am

```
sleep ((3600*1000) + (your_number_of_seconds_until_1am+inside_your_iteration_pacing) *1000));
```